# What does CALayer.contentsScale mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm reading this tutorial, [iOS 7 Blur Effects with GPUImage](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60968/ios-7-blur-effects-gpuimage). I have read the document, this variable means `x px / y pt`.  But I don't get this line of code.

```
_blurView.layer.contentsScale = (MENUSIZE / 320.0f) * 2;
```

What's the logic behind this line? How should I determine the `contentsScale` in my code?

If I don't set the `contentsScale`, which is default to 2.0, the screen looks like:
[image]

But after I set it to `(MENUSIZE / 320.0f) * 2`, the screen is:
[image]

This is strange because the `contentsScale` decreased but the image grow bigger. `MENUSIZE` is 150.0f.

Comment: The intention behind this is to render the bitmap that represents the content of this layer in `x2` (retina) scale factor. As the documentation suggests you could provide the device's screen factor here (`[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`) Read more about it in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW158)

Comment: @Alladinian Thanks for your comment. But I still don't know what does `(MENUSIZE / 320.0f)` mean.

Comment: `MENUSIZE / 320.0f` is merely a repetition of the `contentsRect` height he used earlier. Since this is the height of the `contentsRect`, he adjusts the `contentsScale` to twice this value. Keep in mind that this is just a step along the way in his reasoning. He probably doesn't intend for you to misuse `contentsScale` in this way. The only practical realistic values are 1 and 2. To adjust the scaling of the drawing within the layer, he should have applied a transform.

Comment: Or it could just be a misprint, since later he sets the `contentsScale` to 2, which seems much more reasonable.

Comment: @matt If `contentsScale` is 2.0, then the image is displayed like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MwJP3.png

Answer (score 2):

`contentsScale` determines the size of the backing store bitmap, so that the bitmap will work on both nonretina and retina screens.

Let's say you make a layer (CALayer) into which you intend to draw. Lets say its size is 100x100. Then to make this layer look good on a double-resolution screen, you will want its `contentsScale` to be `2.0`. This means that behind the scenes the bitmap is 200x200. But it is transformed so that you still treat it as 100x100 when you draw into it; you think in points, just as you normally would, and the backing store is scaled to match the doubled pixels of a retina device.

In most cases you don't have to worry about this because if a layer is the main layer of a view, its `contentSize` is set automatically for the current device. But if you create a layer yourself, in code, out of whole cloth, then setting its `contentsScale` based on the scale of the main UIScreen is up to you.

Comment: I think the fact that, you must set `contentsScale` whenever you make a CALayer from scratch, must be the single "most-forgotten thing" in all of iOS !  I mean who knew this ?!  There are thousands of example code fragments around of how to draw this and that in a layer, I've never seen `contentsScale`  mentioned!